# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available:

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security

I was trying to update the spring security to 5.7.3 as WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated so I have changed the code according to that but its still not working.
Please note I am using active directory authentication (ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider).

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfigAD implements WebMvcConfigurer
{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Value( "${ad.domain}" )
    private String AD_DOMAIN;

    @Value( "${ad.url}" )
    private String AD_URL;

    @Value( "${ad.searchfilter}")
    private String SEARCH_FILTER;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigPDF configPdf;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private MyUserDetailService userDetailsService;



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
    {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);


        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/resources/**" ).permitAll().antMatchers( "/css/**" ).permitAll().antMatchers( "/img/**" ).permitAll().antMatchers( "/images/**" ).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage( "/login.html" ).loginProcessingUrl( "/login" )
                .permitAll().successHandler( formLoginSuccessHandler() );//.failureHandler( ( request, response, exception ) -> response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "UNAUTHORIZED" ) );
        http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/logout", "GET" ) ).logoutSuccessUrl( "/" ).deleteCookies( "JSESSIONID", "user", "login" ).invalidateHttpSession( true ).clearAuthentication( true );
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http.rememberMe().key( "uniqueAndSecret" );
        http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl( "/login.html" );
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authenticationManager( authenticationManager(authManagerBuilder));
        return http.build();

    }
```

here is AuthenticationManager  and AuthenticationProvider

```
 @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager( AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder  ) throws Exception
    {
        log.info( "DO some Authentication Manger things" );
       return (AuthenticationManager)authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService( userDetailsService).and.build();

    }
```

```
  @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        log.info( "Authenticate: "+AD_DOMAIN+", "+AD_URL );
        //log.info( "Search_Filter: "+SEARCH_FILTER );
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider( AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL );
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions( true );
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials( true );
        provider.setSearchFilter( SEARCH_FILTER );
        return provider;
    }
```

I am getting below error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 104 more
```

Custom MyUserDetailService class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService
{

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername( String username ) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi & Welcome! One eye-catcher: "security config" implementing "MVC configurer" is rather strange.. (you didn't complete the class..) why do you need this?

Comment: Note , Earlier there was no need to defined custom UserDetailsService for me

Comment: @Api It looks good, except that you return `null` instead the user.

Comment: I am not sure how I can return a user , Do you have some example in case of active directory LDAP ? @dur

Answer (score 0):

See the blog article [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) for information on how to migrate away from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. It does not appear that you are following the recommendations there, so that would be a good starting point.

Take a look specifically at the section on [configuring LDAP](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter#ldap-authentication) which details how to publish an `AuthenticationManager` `@Bean` instead of using `http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)` as in your example. Building the authentication manager the way your example illustrates is not the intended usage, and so is likely the cause of the issue you're facing.

If this blog article does not help clear up the error you're receiving, feel free to update the question with your latest configuration and comment on this answer and I can look at it again.

**Update**

See also [#11926](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11926).

Comment: Can you please show some example with Active directory LDAP as I am not able to relate with it

Comment: See the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/ldap.html#_active_directory).

Comment: i meant the example for Userdetailservice example where they are using active directory in security . 
as if you can see my code above i am not doing anything in MyUserDetailService but yes it is working but i am still curious to know the right way of doing it  .

Comment: The `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` does not use a `UserDetailsService`, and instead uses AD directly. See [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/f9f41047cf271c69e388a7c960bd154a00bdceba/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/ad/ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.java#L167).